# Regex: Remove particular repetead-words from tags in several html pages

Tags: regex, window, notepad++

I have this text with many `&nbsp;` under the tag `<p class="my_class">`

```
 <p class="my_class">An Extension&nbsp;of Java for Event Correlation. 571 geographical/logical coordinates, or sources. Henceforth,&nbsp;we will use the term&nbsp;events to refer to&nbsp;both the incidents underlying such&nbsp;events as well as to their incarnations&nbsp;and notifications</p>
```

I want to select this tag and replace all `&nbsp;` with empty space in several html pages.

First of all, I select the tag and the content:  `(?s)<p class="my_class">([^<]*)</p>`

Then I try to include `&nbsp;` into this regex formula so as to select all `&nbsp;`

`(?s)<p class="my_class">.*?&nbsp;([^<]*)</p>`  but does't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: See [an alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48201572/3832970) to replace all `&nbsp;`s in specified `p` tag in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regular expression:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|<p\s+class="my_class">)(?:(?!</p>).)*?\K&nbsp;
```

Or, to make sure we only replace inside one node inner HTML:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|<p\s+class="my_class">)[^<]*?\K&nbsp;
```

Replace with a space.

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|<p\s+class="my_class">)` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or the `<p class="my_class">` substring (the space can be any whitespace due to `\s`)
- `(?:(?!</p>).)*?` - any char (note that *`.` matches newline* option should be ON), zero or more occurrences, as few as possible, that does not start a `</p>` sequence - OR -
- `[^<]*?` - any chars other than `<`, 0+ occurrences but as few as possible
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `&nbsp;` - match and consume the `&nbsp;` text (that will get replaced with a space)

[image]